# batch script to display only few words from each line of a text file

Tags: batch-file

We have a log file like below.

I need a batch script to display the output from `/soft`. i.e., the output must look like:

```
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPX_RAD.xml
```

It should not display the whole path.

The script should read the log files from `D:\custom.txt` and 
print the output to different file like `SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPX_RAD.xml`

```
=========================================================================== 
                               Custom FILES                                 
=========================================================================== 
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\02-07-2012_2108\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPX_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\02-07-2012_2108\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\05-07-2012_1950\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPX_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\05-07-2012_1950\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\06-07-2012_1949\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\09-07-2012_1948\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPO_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\09-07-2012_1948\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\11-07-2012_1946\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPO_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\11-07-2012_1946\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\17-07-2012_1942\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\19-07-2012_1938\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPO_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\23-07-2012_1939\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPO_RAD.xml
Z:\FCUBS_11.3.1.1.0EURABOILM_SKD\23-07-2012_1939\SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
```

Comment: You need to show the work you've done trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>modified.log (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in (original.log) do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    echo !ln:*\SOFT\=SOFT\!
  )
)
```

The FOR /F statement reads and processes all lines in the file. You can read about it by typing `FOR /?` or `HELP FOR` from the command line.

The critical bit is `!ln:*\SOFT\=SOFT\!` - that searches the text for "\SOFT\" and deletes everything from the beginning of the line through "\SOFT\" and replaces the deleted bit with "SOFT\". You can read about string search and replace by typing `SET /?` or `HELP SET` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The one liner:

```
D:\>FOR /F "tokens=4,5,6,7,8 delims=\\" %G in (infile.txt) DO @echo %G\%H\%I\%J\%K

SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPX_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPX_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPO_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPO_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPO_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICCREFPO_RAD.xml
SOFT\MAIN\Core\RADXML\ICDREDMN_RAD.xml
```

Comment: There is no need to double up the backslash. Also, `FOR /F "tokens=3* delims=\" %A in (infile.txt) DO @echo %B` is simpler and more robust. Finally, this type of solution strips out the header lines, which may not be acceptable.